# table setAttribute not working properly in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

I am trying to build an application that generates a custom list item which will be displayed on the screen dynamicly(like contact list update), and have the following code which works pretty well on both IE and Firefox.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

    .divCss table{
    width:100%;
    height:130px;
    }

    .divCss {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:solid 1px #c0c0c0;
    background-color:#999000;
    font-size:11px;
    font-family:verdana;
    color:#000;
    }

.divCss table:hover{
    background-color :#FF9900;
}

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">   

    var elementCounts = 0;

    function myItemClicked(item)
    {
        alert("item clicked:"+item.id);

    }

    function createItem()
    {
        var pTag = document.createElement("p");
            var tableTag = document.createElement("table");

            tableTag.id = "" + (elementCounts++);

            tableTag.setAttribute("border","1");
            tableTag.setAttribute("cellpadding","5");
            tableTag.setAttribute("width","100%");
            tableTag.setAttribute("height","130px");
            tableTag.onclick = function() {myItemClicked(this);};

                var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");
                    var tr1Tag = document.createElement("tr");

                        var tdImageTag = document.createElement("td");
                        tdImageTag .setAttribute("width","100px");
                        tdImageTag .setAttribute("rowspan","2");

                            var imgTag = document.createElement("img");
                            imgTag.setAttribute("width","100px");
                            imgTag.setAttribute("height","100px");
                            imgTag.id = "avatar";

                        tdImageTag .appendChild(imgTag);

                        var tdTextTag= document.createElement("td");
                        tdTextTag.setAttribute("height","30%");
                        tdTextTag.setAttribute("nowrap","1");
                        tdTextTag.setAttribute("style","font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;");
                        tdTextTag.id = "text";
                        tdTextTag.innerHTML = "text";

                    tr1Tag.appendChild(tdImageTag);
                    tr1Tag.appendChild(tdTextTag);

                    var tr2Tag = document.createElement("tr");
                        var tdAnotherTextTag = document.createElement("td");
                        tdAnotherTextTag.setAttribute("valign","top");
                        tdAnotherTextTag.id = "anotherText";
                        tdAnotherTextTag.innerHTML = "Another Text";

                    tr2Tag.appendChild(tdAnotherTextTag );

                tBody.appendChild(tr1Tag);
                tBody.appendChild(tr2Tag);
            tableTag.appendChild(tBody);
        tableTag.className ="divCss";
        pTag.appendChild(tableTag);
        document.getElementById("list").appendChild(pTag);
    }

    function clearList()
    {
        document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "";
        elementCounts = 0;
    }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
   <input id="btn1" type="button" value="create item" onclick="createItem();" />
   <input id="btn2" type="button" value="clear list" onclick="clearList();" />
<div id="list" class="divCss" style="overflow: scroll;"></div>    
</body> 
</html>
```

This code generates a new table element on click of "create item" button and adds it inside a div element on the main page.

The table element is supposed to be like the following

```
+---------------+--------------------+
|               |        Text        |
|  Image with   |                    |
|  rowspan of   +--------------------|
|       2       |     Another Text   |
|               |                    |
+---------------+--------------------+
```

The above code does showup properly on firefox, however on IE, the rowspan is kinda ignored and the output looks like

```
+---------------+--------------------+
|  Image with   |        Text        |
|rowspan ignored|                    |
|---------------+--------------------|
| Another Text  |                    |
|               |                    |
+---------------+--------------------+
```

Can anyone help me why this must be happening? I also checked writing direct tags ( instead of using createElement and appendChild), and that works, but the dynamic generation seems to be problamatic. Am I doing anything worng here?

Also, after adding the generated table elements in the div element ( "list" ), there seems to be some gap between consecutive table elements and am not able to remove it even if i specify margin and padding as 0 in div tag.

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks.

**EDIT: About the gap between table elements inside div.**
Here is the output as expected: ( This works in jsfiddle as suggessted by Shadow Wizard ).

```
+------------------------------------+
| List Element 1                     |
+---------------+--------------------+
|               |        Text        |
|  Image with   |                    |
|  rowspan of   +--------------------|
|       2       |     Another Text   |
|               |                    |
+---------------+--------------------+
| List Element 2                     |
+---------------+--------------------+
|               |        Text        |
|  Image with   |                    |
|  rowspan of   +--------------------|
|       2       |     Another Text   |
|               |                    |
+---------------+--------------------+
| List Element 3                     |
+---------------+--------------------+
|               |        Text        |
|  Image with   |                    |
|  rowspan of   +--------------------|
|       2       |     Another Text   |
|               |                    |
+---------------+--------------------+
```

Here is the output that i get on chrome, ie, firefox..

```
+------------------------------------+
| List Element 1                     |
+---------------+--------------------+
|               |        Text        |
|  Image with   |                    |
|  rowspan of   +--------------------|
|       2       |     Another Text   |
|               |                    |
+---------------+--------------------+
              Gap
+------------------------------------+
| List Element 2                     |
+---------------+--------------------+
|               |        Text        |
|  Image with   |                    |
|  rowspan of   +--------------------|
|       2       |     Another Text   |
|               |                    |
+---------------+--------------------+
               Gap
+------------------------------------+
| List Element 3                     |
+---------------+--------------------+
|               |        Text        |
|  Image with   |                    |
|  rowspan of   +--------------------|
|       2       |     Another Text   |
|               |                    |
+---------------+--------------------+
```

Sorry for explaining things like this. I was not able to upload my snapshots. However, you can see the difference between jsfiddle and other browser effects by opening the page as html file in any browser.

EDIT (Shadow_Wizard) - here is the screenshot:  [image]

Comment: Try `tdImageTag.rowSpan = 2;` instead.

Comment: :) That did work. Thanks for the help. Any idea about the gaps between different items?

Comment: There is a space between `tdImageTag` and  `.setAttribute("rowspan","2");`, should it not be `tdImageTag.setAttribute("rowspan","2");`?

Comment: Sorry for that, it wasn't there before, might have gotten while changin the names. However, even if the gap is not there, it still wasn't working. Confirmed it again right now..

Comment: @Puneet see my answer, maybe it's the `width` and `height` being set incorrectly as well. If no luck can you put example in jsFiddle or link to the live site?

Comment: @Puneet - can you check the discussion between myself and Jakub in Jakub's answer below? Check the document mode, if it is "Quirks" or "IE7" then change to "rowSpan" or change the doctype to ensure recent standards. Only IE8 Standards and above support the lowercase `rowspan` in `setAttribute`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IE, the `attributes` are pretty limited and better be set "directly" and not via `setAttribute`.

Try this instead:

```
tdImageTag.rowSpan = 2;
```

Same for width and height: those better be set as part of the `style`:

```
imgTag.style.width = "100px";
imgTag.style.height = "100px";
```

Edit: by gaps do you mean the parts marked with red circles?
[image]

Edit II: if you see difference between jsFiddle and your own file it might mean you're missing DOCTYPE declaration. Try adding this line on top of your code, above the `<html>` tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

jsFiddle is adding such line by itself, you can View Source to see it.

Also, I saw you're running the file locally... that's also not good you better run it as part of website to simulate "real" web page.

Comment: Thanks for the rowSpan. It got sorted out. However the spacing problem is not with the imgTag. Its with the tableTag. The gap is between two tables. It doesn't come for the very first object, but start coming after adding more objects.

Comment: @Puneet please go to this [test case](http://jsfiddle.net/m2ArC/) add some tables, take screenshot and explain what exactly is wrong, I can't figure it out sorry..

Comment: @Shadow Please see my edit. Couldn't upload/attach image to my edit so had to explain this way.

Comment: @Shadow No, thats not the gap i am referring to. The one you showed in the image above happened as the image height is 100px and the table height is 130px. and changing table height to 100px removes that gap. 
I am actually referring to the gap between individual table elements. (for example. there is a gap between second element's "text" and previous element's "Another Text". Again not able to upload image. :(

Comment: @Puneet can you manually upload it [here](http://imgur.com/) then I'll add it to your post as "permanent" upload?

Comment: @Puneet I've added it to your post.. see my new edit for possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try `tdImageTag.setAttribute("rowSpan","2");` - it needs to be the upper case S
The gaps between the table elements may happen because the default cellspacing try this code: `tableTag.cellSpacing=0;`

Also if you are using the strict mode you can set the cellspacing in the css:
`table.divCss {border-spacing:0;}`

Comment: It doesn't need to be uppercase "S" when setting the attribute, it only needs to be uppercase when using `.rowSpan = 2`

Comment: @anothershrubery ??? Did you run a test in the browser? I have tested it in IE8 and that is actually the solution.

Comment: I see the point, this must be dependent on working in strict and quirks mode then. The page in this example runs in strict mode. I have done my test in quirks mode - as he does by not specifying the DOCTYPE.

Comment: Actually you may well have hit upon something there. The lowercase shouldn't matter if the doctype is correct but if it is running in quirks mode the OP code won't work. @Puneet - ensure you are not running in quirks mode, and if you have no control over the doctype then just change the "s" to uppercase. Good spot Jakub.